# Angular - How to simulate an HttpErrorResponse?

Tags: html, angular, error-handling, httpresponse, angular-httpclient

I am trying to test my code on how my application would handle a particular HttpErrorResponse (302 redirect specifically).
Is there a way for me to simulate a request on my application so that it will throw a type of HttpErrorResponse?
I am not talking about in unit test, but in actual run-time execution of my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test this kind of response without having to modify your backend, you could try some e2e testing using protractor or [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html) which can mock your server's responses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can throw error with any message in your resp observable

```
    const resp = this.http.post(`your api endpoint`);

    return resp.pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
            throw throwError({
                    status: 302,
                    message: 'error message'
            });
        }),
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            throw err
        })
    );
```

above code will get into catchError block with given err